# Programatically get product collection which are exists in array of categry ids

Tags: product, product-collection, programmatically, programming

I am working on magento product collection query. My requirement to fetch products which are present in array of category.

Example: $all_selected_categories = array('15','35','48','75');

Above categories are from many seperate websites.

My query is:

```
$collection_check = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')   
                    ->getCollection()       
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('entity_id','name','description','created_at','price','status','parent_id'))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);        
$collection_check->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id',null, 'left');     
$collection_check->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' =>array('finset' => $all_selected_categories)));
```

But i am getting error of already exists of id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85263/get-products-belonging-to-multiple-categories-from-set-of-products-in-another-ca/85265#85265

Comment: Yes works correctly....

Comment: @AkhileshPatel is any possible duplicate link for this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86114/programatically-get-product-collection-which-are-exists-in-array-of-website-ids

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$collection_check->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => $all_selected_categories)));
```

to

```
 $collection_check = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect(array('entity_id','name','description','created_at','price','status','parent_id')) ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $all_selected_categories));
```

Comment: Not working giving same error

Comment: update answer check it

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the following line

```
$collection_check->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

at the end.